# Calling a Secondary Products Variant ID (Javascript, Shopify)

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I've got some Javascript I'm using to call the VariantIDs of two products showing on the same page in Shopify.

I've been able to show the primary and secondary products, split the items into two forms on the same product page. I'm able to select both products, I'm getting the correct variant ID arrays for both when inspecting the page.

I'm now looking to use the below JS to find the IDs so that I can pass them to the cart.

Below is the code I'm using, all of the code relating to the Primary Product is working fine, but I'm unable to get the Secondary ID. I'll admit I don't know enough about JS to understand what I can and can't duplicate and what parts I need to amend.

I hope this is enough to understand what I'm trying to achieve

```
function GetPrimaryVariantID()
  {
    var result;
    var primarySelectedVariants = document.querySelectorAll(".primary_form_options input:checked");
    for ( var i = 0; i < primaryProductData.length; i++ )
      {
        var product = primaryProductData[ i ];
        var matches = 0;
        var numberOfOptionsInProduct = 1;
        if (product.option2!="")
        {
          if (product.option3!="")
          {
            numberOfOptionsInProduct = 3;
          }
          else 
          {
            numberOfOptionsInProduct = 2;
          }
        }
        for ( var j = 0; j < primarySelectedVariants.length; j++ )
          {
            var primarySelectedVariant = primarySelectedVariants [ j ];
            var optionIndex = primarySelectedVariant.getAttribute ( "data-optionindex" );
            var optionValue = primarySelectedVariant.value;
            var propertyName = "option"+optionIndex;
            if (product[propertyName]==optionValue)
              {
                matches++;
              } 
          }
        if (matches==numberOfOptionsInProduct)
        {
          result=product.variantid;
          break;
        }
      }
      return result;
  }




function GetSecondaryVariantID() 
  {
    var result;
    var secondarySelectedVariants = document.querySelectorAll(".secondary_form_options input:checked");
    for ( var k = 0; k < secondaryProductData.length; k++ )
      {
        var product = secondaryProductData[ k ];
        var matches = 0;
        var numberOfOptionsInProduct = 1;
        if (product.option2!="")
        {
          if (product.option3!="")
          {
            numberOfOptionsInProduct = 3;
          }
          else 
          {
            numberOfOptionsInProduct = 2;
          }
        }
        for ( var l = 0; l < secondarySelectedVariants.length; l++ )
          {
            var secondarySelectedVariant = secondarySelectedVariants [ l ];
            var optionIndex = secondarySelectedVariant.getAttribute ( "data-optionindex" );
            var optionValue = secondarySelectedVariant.value;
            var propertyName = "option"+optionIndex;
            if (product[propertyName]==optionValue)
              {
                matches++;
              } 
          }
        if (matches==numberOfOptionsInProduct)
        {
          result=product.variantid;
          break;
        }
      }
      return result;
  }
```

Comment: So you get null as answer from the second function? The result of the function depends on how the HTML is structued. Assumin that everything is correct (I can't check as I don't have the HTML code), couldn't be that you don't have a second variant?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The HTML seems fine, I've got the second variant showing though I've used this to define the secondary product as I'm pulling it from a metafield

```
<div class="product-page__form__options secondary_form_options">
      {% assign secondary = product.metafields["clubl"].co_ord_product.value %}
```

The second variants show and when clicked they give the correct results in the console, I just seem to have the JS in a muddle trying to target it and get the result ready to send to cart